# Consuming WCF service in android

Tags: android, wcf

I've created this service (using WCF, Azure):

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Service1 : IPMPService
{
    public int Dummy()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Where IPMPService is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPMPService
{
    [WebGet()]
    [OperationContract]
    int Dummy();
}
```

And attempted to consume it in my android app:
1st attempt:

```
String METHOD_NAME = "DummyRequest";
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String URL = "http://tyty.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tyty.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc/Dummy";

String res = "";
try {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    // to get the data
    String resultData = result.toString();
    res = resultData;
    // 0 is the first object of data
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res = e.getMessage();
    }
```

result: SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:ActionNotSupported' faultstring: 'The message with Action 'http://tyty.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc/Dummy' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

2nd attempt (taken from [here](http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2008/08/consuming-web-services-from-android.html)):

```
String SERVER_HOST = "http://tyty.cloudapp.net";
int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
String URL1 = "/Service1.svc/Dummy";
String keywords = null;
HttpEntity entity = null;
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL1);
try {
HttpResponse response = client.execute(target, get);
entity = response.getEntity();
keywords = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
if (entity != null)
        try {
        entity.consumeContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
  }
}
```

Result: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://tyty.cloudapp.net": No address associated with hostname

I've also created a (working) client in c#, here is its App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPMPService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://tyty.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPMPService"
          contract="IPMPService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPMPService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As mentioned, both attempts in Android failed. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to do it right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first attempt is pretty close. There are just two fixes needed:

```
String METHOD_NAME = "Dummy";
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String URL = "http://tyty.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IPMPService/Dummy";

String res = "";
try {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    // to get the data
    String resultData = result.toString();
    res = resultData;
    // 0 is the first object of data
} catch (Exception e) {
    res = e.getMessage();
}
```

The first one is the method name: it just `Dummy` (instead of `DummyRequest`). The second is the SOAP action: it's `http://tempuri.org/IPMPService/Dummy`.

Both can be derived from the WSDL. Your operation is defined as:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Dummy">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPMPService/Dummy" message="tns:IPMPService_Dummy_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPMPService/DummyResponse" message="tns:IPMPService_Dummy_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

If you then look at the `IPMPService_Dummy_InputMessage` message type, the element is called `Dummy`:

```
<wsdl:message name="IPMPService_Dummy_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Dummy"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

And the SOAP action is found here:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Dummy">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPMPService/Dummy" style="document"/>
    ...
```

Comment: I can give you the bounty only in 18 hrs. But may God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RESTConnection extends Global 
{


    Global objglobal=Global.getInstance();

    private static String SERVICE_URI = "your service path";

    public JSONObject GetCashierLogin(String UserName, String Password)
    {
        new ArrayList<String>();  

        JSONObject jObj = null;  
        try 
        {

            SERVICE_URI=objglobal.getConnectionString();
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI+ "/LoginByUserIdAndPassword?Username=" + UserName + "&password=" + Password + "");
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            String bufferLogin = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(bufferLogin);

            if (jsonArray != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    jObj=(JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                }
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj;
    }
```